# ERD: manager and hotel, going from a one:many to a many:many relationship

Tags: many-to-many, erd, entity-relationship

Currently, a hotel is managed by a single manager only. A manager can manage 0 to many hotels, as shown in the below diagram (unfortunately I can't post pictures yet, however I have provided the links:

https://postimg.cc/nXJtL2n5

Now there is a change such that some hotels will be managed by multiple managers, and others will still be managed by a single manager. For example, a hotel used to have a single manager, now it has a bookings manager, a cleaning manager, and a maintenance manager. I want all of these manager roles to appear in the HOTEL entity.

The below image is what I have so far.

https://postimg.cc/mzDP5RqQ

Is there a way to link the hotel with the new manager roles?

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate entity for each of the managers e.g booking, cleaning and maintenance manager as a seperate entity; and then depict the 1:M relationships with the manager and hotels that they are managing. As a PK you need to have a unique key for each of those entitys so you can show the FK in the table they are referencing.

You want to avoid having M:M relationship so they need to be broken down to achieve redundancy in your final database design.

Comment: Is there a way to do it such that all of the manager roles (booking, cleaning, etc.) are all in the one table? If in the future more roles are added would it be efficient to have to create a new table each time?

Comment: You want to avoid update, delete and insertion anomalies, so in theory every time you need to update that table everything else will be affected in the process so it's best to create seperate entities